# One-sample Cramer-VonMises test with unknown parameters in python

Tags: python, scipy, scikits, scipy.stats

I am looking for a one-sample Cramer-Von Mises test for a normal distribution with **unknown parameters** in python.

I found some discussion here
   https://github.com/chrisb83/scipy/commit/9274d22fc1ca7ce40596b01322be84c81352899d
but this does not seem to be released?

There is also this:
https://pypi.org/project/scikit-gof/
but these tests only work for fully specified distributions (i.e. known parameters).

Is anyone aware of a CVM-test implementation in python for a normal dist with unknown parameters?

Thanks

Comment: The commit that you linked to is part of a [scipy pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/11119).  It is still under development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test is done on the sample. Here an example using [OpenTURNS](http://openturns.org) in Python.

```
import openturns as ot
```

First let's build a random sample of size 200 from a centered standard Normal distribution
You may haveyour own data:

`sample = ot.Sample([0, 0.3, -0.1, 0.23, -0.5], 1)`

but OpenTurns offers a simple way to build samples

`sample = ot.Normal().getSample(200)`

Now to execute the Cramer-Von Mises normality test you just call this method

```
test_result = ot.NormalityTest.CramerVonMisesNormal(sample)
```

Then print the result

```
print('Component is normal?', test_result.getBinaryQualityMeasure(),
      'p-value=%.6g' % test_result.getPValue(),
      'threshold=%.6g' % test_result.getThreshold())

>>> Component is normal? True 
 p-value=0.624469 
 threshold=0.01
```

But always remember that the threshold is arbitrary and that the test can give false negative even though the sample really comes from a Normal distribution.

If you want to test a sample coming from a Uniform distribution, replace the line 'sample' by: `sample = ot.Uniform().getSample(200)`